# How to create a new average variable for which I have three values in separate rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this

```
     subject treatment time outcome1 outcome2 
1       1         a    1       80       15
2       1         a    2       75       14
3       1         a    3       74       12
4       2         b    1       90       16
5       2         b    2       81       15
6       2         b    3       76       15
```

I would like to create a new variable that is an average of outcome1 values at time 1, 2, 3. I would like to do this for all subjects (40). I would then like to do this for outcome 2 till outcome 22.

I tried this

```
data <- data %>% 
group_by(subject) %>% 
summarise(mkcal = mean(kcal))
```

but it is giving wrong means and deleting all data except for means. When I try mutate instead of summarize it just creates a new column which is a copy of the kcal column. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: dput(head(Data, 20))  <- can you add the result from this to the question. Makes it easily reproducible.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, the output doesn't print for some reason.

Comment: Use `mutate()` rather than `summarize()` to add columns. What do you mean that it's giving the wrong mean? Your example uses `kcal` but that does not appear in the data. It would be best if you included the desired output for your sample input so that possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Comment: I realized my mistake. mutate() works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("outcome")), funs(mean = mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   subject [2]
  subject treatment  time outcome1 outcome2 outcome1_mean outcome2_mean
    <int> <fct>     <int>    <int>    <int>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1       1 a             1       80       15          76.3          13.7
2       1 a             2       75       14          76.3          13.7
3       1 a             3       74       12          76.3          13.7
4       2 b             1       90       16          82.3          15.3
5       2 b             2       81       15          82.3          15.3
6       2 b             3       76       15          82.3          15.3
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "subject treatment time outcome1 outcome2 
1       1         a    1       80       15
           2       1         a    2       75       14
           3       1         a    3       74       12
           4       2         b    1       90       16
           5       2         b    2       81       15
           6       2         b    3       76       15", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! What to do when the outcome names are different from each other? For example abc, def, efg and so on

Comment: Insteaf of `vars(contains("outcome"))`, you can use `.vars = vars(dplyr::matches("(somevar1)|(somevar2)"))`.

Comment: Would this function pick all the variables between (somevar) and (somevar)?

Comment: No, it assumes that there are sets of variables with common column names. Say `somevar1` is a set of variables containing `a` and `somevar2` is a set of variables containing `b`. If all of the column names are unique, you need to use something else.

Comment: Okay, I have unique column names, is there any solution apart from changing column names?

Comment: If your column names contain character(s) and number(s), you can use `vars(matches("[A-Za-z0-9]"))`. Note that it computes a mean also for `time` and `treatment`.